# Android Manifest merger failed after adding module dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, wear-os

I want to add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0` to my android wear app to the detect the location of the watch.

But i am getting following error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:percent:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.
```

My `wear.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.siyaryikmis.jiyan"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:wear:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
}
```

my `wear.AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="de.siyaryikmis.jiyan">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/tree_of_life"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Login2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login2"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.NeedIsSentActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_need_is_sent"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.FailedActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_failed"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for all your suggestions and help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly add tools namespace:

```
< manifest xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    xmlns: tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
```

Then add meta tag：

```
<application>
   ...
   ..
    <meta-data
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="28.0.0" />
</application>
```

Don't forget to add this line in module build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Adding the <meta-data> tag solved my problem.